# Vuesax SCSS animation keyframes not working

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuesax

I'm trying to put some nice style into my Vuesax table. I want to create an animation that will list data. For now I have created something like this:

```
<vs-tr :data="tr" :key="indextr" v-for="(tr, indextr) in data" class="table-open">
```

and style:

```
@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.table-open{
    animation: 1s ease 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
}
```

and this works fine. But I want to list products one by one and I tried something like this:

```
<vs-tr :data="tr" :key="indextr" v-for="(tr, indextr) in data" :style="[{animation: (indextr * 0.1) + 's ease 0s 1 slideInFromLeft'}]">
```

But this is not working. Any ideas how to fix it? Do I need to write keyframes in some other way?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to show your issue?

Comment: Here it is, but don't work here https://jsfiddle.net/jbgh54w1/

Comment: I tried like :style="[{animation: 'rotate ' + (indextr * 0.3) + 's'}]" and it works, but question is how to implement to slideInFromLeft?

Comment: @Dan not really helpful for what am I looking

Comment: @RadeIlijev - Sorry, I chose the wrong duplicate!  Now it's correct:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283989/why-are-css-keyframe-animations-broken-in-vue-components-with-scoped-styling  The problem is with scoped styling and keyframes.